# Select the row with the most recent modified date

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table:

| user_id | name | email | modified_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | a@gmail.com | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | John | b@gmail.com | 2022-01-02 |
| 1 | Lucy | c@gmail.com | 2022-01-03 |
| 2 | Joey | d@gmail.com | 2021-12-24 |
| 3 | Mike | e@gmail.com | 2022-01-01 |
| 3 | Mary | f@gmail.com | 2022-01-02 |

I'm trying to get unique `user_id`'s email with the most recent `modified_date`. This is my expected output:

| user_id | email | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | c@gmail.com | Lucy |
| 2 | d@gmail.com | Joey |
| 3 | f@gmail.com | Mary |

I used `limit 1`, but the output seems to be randomized.

Can somebody help me to sort this out ?

Comment: Copy that, a new tag postresql is added

Comment: Can also please show your SQL statement that you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can go for row_number() with partition by

**Schema (PostgreSQL v10.0)**

```
create table users(user_id integer, name varchar(10),   email varchar(20),  modified_date timestamp);

insert into users 
values
(1  ,'John',    'a@gmail.com',  '2022-01-01'),
(1  ,'John',    'b@gamil.com',  '2022-02-01');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select user_id, email, name
from
(
SELECT user_id, name, email,row_number() over(partition by user_id order by modified_Date desc) as rnk
FROM users
  ) as t
  where rnk = 1;
```

| user_id | email | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | b@gamil.com | John |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/0)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, your query probably looks something like:

```sql
SELECT user_id, email
FROM email_addresses
GROUP BY user_id
```

You'll need to do something a little different

```sql
SELECT email_addresses.*
FROM email_addresses
LEFT OUTER JOIN email_addresses AS b
    ON email_addresses.user_id = b.user_id
    AND b.modified_date > email_addresses.modified_date
WHERE b.user_id IS NULL
```

This works by pairing with a newer record if one exists, and then the `where` clause requires the pair was unsuccessful.